# How to properly resolve useEffect exhaustive dependencies when hooks used cause infinite rerenders when added to the dependencies

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a component that needs to update when the url's query param is changed.

Currently this works fine, except that I get an exhaustive dependencies warning because I don't have the setQuery inside of the array. If I add it, I get an infinite loop.

**What is the solution here to remove the warning?**

```js
  import { useQueryParam, withDefault, StringParam } from 'use-query-params';
  const [query, setQuery] = useQueryParam<string>(
    'query',
    withDefault(StringParam, ''),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery(query);
  }, [query]); // adding setQuery will cause an infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop is because:

useEffect will get invoked every time its dependencies change. Here dependency is query.

```
 [query]);
```

Every time it gets invoked , we are setting (updating) query.

```
setQuery(query);
```

causing useEffect to invoke again.

Comment: This isn't the case. `setQuery(query);` doesn't update the query variable. It's not causing an infinite loop here. What IS causing the infinite loop is if I add setQuery to the dependencies list.